# Margin-right difference Chrome and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, margin

Using [**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin the following [**example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obwvRg) was created, and the issue I am currently stuck with is that margin right that I set up for `div` with images in text doesn't look same in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. I've tried and add [normilize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) and [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), but the issue is still there.

I've presented the code for 940px and 1366px resolutions, there is also min 1px resolution so you can hide the general code for easier look.

**CSS with margin-right on line 323 for 940 res**

```
.composition-place {
      width: 30.24%;
      height: auto;
      margin-right: 4.55%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      float: left;
    }
```

**CSS with margin-right on line 382 for 1366 res**

```
.composition-place {
      width: 22.845%;
      height: auto;
      margin-right: 2.9%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      float: left;
    }
```

Can you please suggest how the following issue can be figured out?

Comment: Have your tried `box-sizing: border-box` CSS option?

Comment: I've added * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
       -o-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}   as a global rule, maybe some more suggestions?

Comment: what should the output desired?

Comment: I feel like in fire fox the margins are counted a bit bigger, so in every @media the page lacks 1 column with images, so I would like to achieve the look like in chrome, opera and safari.

Comment: I see three columns in both FF and Chrome.